# Clip-path not working on videos

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I have been trying to display an image and on hover, a video would start replacing the image, I used Javascript for the hover functions.

I did this using "poster" in the video tag like this:`

```
<div class="video">

    <video id="videotest" poster="images/img.jpg">
        <source src="images/bkg.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        Can't use videos here.
    </video>

</div>
```

However, I would like the video to be the same size as the image. The video is 1280*720, and the image is 677-611.
I tried to use clip-path to adapt the video but it doesn't work, here is my CSS:

```
.video {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    clip-path:inset(0 978px 611px 301px);
    -webkit-clip-path:inset(0 978px 611px 301px);
}
```

I tried applying this style to .video, #videotest and source, it still didn't work as expected.

Is it impossible to use clip-path with videos in HTML5? If so, how can I do it, and if not, how can I make it work?

I will explain myself a little more:
I don't want the image to resize, keeping proportions or not, I just would like to cut off, for example, some pixels left and right, so the image in poster is exactly the same size as the video replacing it. Clip-path seemed to correspond to what I was looking for, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Where can I upload the video(It's only 3 MB)?
I tried TinyPic and vid.me but it doesn't display.
Can I keep using the video tag, so I can use poster attribute, or I have to use the iframe, and upload for example on Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

Well Here is the code in HTML you add in the video tag **poster="transparent.jpg"** to call it by css background and **preload="none"** to make the poster visible then you make sure to add video's extension that works with the browsers in **source** tag inside the **video** tag Unfortunately I couldn't finger out extension that works with safari, It could works if you add the video as one extension to your source folder but I never try

```css
.video {
        background:transparent url('http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/jw-html-config/posters/big-buck-bunny-preview.jpg') no-repeat;
 background-size:  677px 611px;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 677px; 
        height:611px;
}

video { 
            width: 677px; 
            height:611px;
            object-fit:inherit;
     }
```

```html
     <div class="video">
         <video controls="true" id="videotest" poster="transparent.jpg" preload="none">
             <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
         </video>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It doesn't exactly works though, I wanted to adapt the video, and not the image. 
Moreover, I can't see the image when I put it in background, behind the video, even with a transparent image.
As for Safari, it looks like you just need to have quicktime on your computer to be able to see the video, I didn't try it though.

Comment: Just Add object-fit:inherit; in CSS to free the video form auto scaling, because by default if we trying to change the video height it will change the width automatically and inversion too.

Comment: This time it adapts the size of the image, and not of the video. Thanks though!

Comment: It adapts the video and the image too at the same time unfortunately it works on Opera, Chrome, Firefox but not (Safari and IE).

Comment: All what you need to do is : 
If you want to change the height you have to change the height in "background-size","height" in the video and in the .video so All of them have to be same and the same of the height as well, And I'm working on Safari and IE.

Comment: I added more explanations, I thought I wasn't very clear sorry, your last answer correspond well, and if I can cut the sides of the video, I'll use it like this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome I'm glad to know that, The problem and what it takes me long because I don't have any example of your video so I'm not sure about  "if I can cut the sides of the video" and I don't know why and what is the problem unless if because 'Safari and IE'.And if you can vote for my code to because this answer is part with the code too, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.svg-clipped-text {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
    clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
}



<video loop width="100%" height="100%" autoplay class="svg-clipped-text">
    <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/bouncyballs.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<div class="demo">
    <svg height="0" width="0">

        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <path id="SVGID_3_" d="M770.5,483c3.1,12.8-2.2,30.7-11.8,39.7L498,770c-9.5,9.1-27.7,13.4-40.3,9.7L113.2,677.5
            c-12.6-3.7-25.4-17.3-28.5-30L0.9,298c-3.1-12.8,2.2-30.7,11.8-39.7L273.4,11C282.9,2,301-2.4,313.6,1.3l344.5,102.1
            c12.6,3.7,25.4,17.3,28.5,30L770.5,483z"/>
        </clipPath> 
    </svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks